# Matlab parallel computing toolbox: what really means "threads x workers"

Tags: multithreading, matlab, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

I have a laptop with 2 physical cores and the MatLab parallel computing toolbox. I'm struggling with what actually a *thread* is and **what actually means "2 threads for a worker"**

Let's say I start a parallel pool with 2 workers, and I assign the number of computational thread x worker to 2. I can't understand "physically" what's going on. For instance, in the 
 MatLab documentation's [example](https://it.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/decide-when-to-use-parfor.html#bvi2qb4):

- a thread would be "the comptutation of a spectral radius", right?
- Also, if I have a worker with two threads, does this two threads run in parallel? I don't think so, as I think that they can run in parallel only if they are on *physical* different cores.

I googled a lot, really, but can't find an answer to this.

Comment: Its more complicated. Modern computers can do multitrheading with a single physical core due to smart reorganization of instructions. Say that one thread is reading for RAM. This takes time, while the processor waits for that info to arrive, it can do other things. In some sense, all taks running in your computer use, at least, one thread. You likely have hundreds of them running, yet not that many physical cores.

Comment: @AnderBiguri thanks! But for what concerns Matlab example: in that case, what does it mean to have "a worker with two threads"?  Does it mean that half of the iterations are assigned to the first worker (which may correspond to a physical core), and then on this physical core we have multithreading?